# How to remove all child nodes from parent TreeIter from Gtk.TreeStore?

Tags: c#, gtk#

Given a TreeStore and TreeIter, how do you remove all of the child nodes from a parent WITHOUT deleting the parent? None of these are selected, just want to clear a set of nodes under a parent.

```
ParentNode
  +- Child 1
  +- Child 2
  +- Child 3
```

So remove "Child 1-3" and keep ParentNode.

This needs to be looped somehow over something:

```
        TreePath p = this.game_store.GetPath (this.players_iter);
        p.Down ();
        TreeIter i = new TreeIter ();
        this.game_store.GetIter (out i, p);
        this.game_store.Remove (ref i);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
while (this.game_store.Remove (ref i));
```

[Documentation of Remove function says](http://api.gtkd.org/src/gtk/TreeStore.html):

*"@iter is set to the next valid row at that level,"
"Return %TRUE if @iter is still valid, %FALSE if not."*

Comment: Ah, so simple I am really not understanding the core concept of the store.

Answer (score 1):

Try the clear() method.

For your reference:

http://api.gtkd.org/src/gtk/TreeStore.html